# How to connect pgxpool to the master and replica hosts with possibility of write to the table?

Tags: postgresql, go, database-replication, pgx

Got host variable equals to the database hosts

```
host=<masters fqdn>,<replicas fqdn>
```

But, when the program tries to write something in db, it gets an error:

```
cannot set transaction read-write mode during recovery (SQLSTATE 0A000)
```

Looks like pgx tries to write into the replica , instead of master

I found out, this problem can be fixed by changing connection opts:

```
cfg.Config.RuntimeParams["target_session_attrs"] = "read-write"
```

But this doesn't work

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: target_session_attrs=primary doesn't works also

Comment: I solved this by creating client-side witness, which detects and changes current master every 15 seconds (if ```SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()``` == true ,then host is replica)

Answer (score 0):

Your server is in recovery mode and you're attempting to perform a write operation on a replica which is typically read-only during recovery.

You need to set `hot_standby = on` in `postgresql.conf` on replicas and confirm `max_wal_senders` and `wal_level = replica` on the primary. In your primary server's `postgresql.conf`, the `synchronous_standby_names` parameter is probably set to an empty string, which should be changed to your standby name. And, remove any `recovery.conf` or `recovery.signal` file there is - these files are used to control the recovery process and might contain settings that affect read-only vs. read-write behavior.

Restart the server on both, the primary and the replica for the settings to take effect.

Comment: Replica and master alredy stay in hots_standby mode , both placed in cloud, so I suppose synchronous_standby_names fills automatically